# UICollectionView autolayout doesn't animate when using setCollectionViewLayout:animated:completion:

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

A `UICollectionView` with cells that have a label inside each with the constraints:

```
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x8a7b030 ItemCell:0x8a7a610.centerX == UILabel:0x8a7a9b0.centerX>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x8a7b060 ItemCell:0x8a7a610.centerY == UILabel:0x8a7a9b0.centerY>
```

When calling `setCollectionViewLayout:animated:completion:` the cell animates fine but the label inside jumps to the final position at the start of the animation.

When using different constrains such as spacing to nearest neighbour, the same problem occurs.

When using `startInteractiveTransitionToCollectionViewLayout:completion:` the label animates fine. I have tried calling `finishInteractiveTransition` right after `startInteractiveTransitionToCollectionViewLayout:completion:` but that doesn't seem like the best way to fix it.

I've also had the same problem with a separate `UICollectionViewCell` xib. The xib was set to non-autolayout withe the autoresizing mask of the `UILabel` set to: `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth`

Comment: Are the cells subclassed?

Comment: Yeah ItemCell is a UICollectionViewCell which has a UILabel